# Unable to connect h2o server python3

Tags: python-3.x, h2o

I have a problem trying to connect to the h2o server. The first time i'm able to do it. But the second time i get this error:

```
[18:56.78] H2OConnectionError: Unexpected HTTP error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=54321): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/Cloud (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3041303dd8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

At the begining of my script i have:

```
h2o.init(ip="127.0.0.1", port="54321")
```

I down know if the first time the connection didnt close. Any body can help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you connect to Flow? Have a look at the logs, and post anything that looks interesting. Which OS? Look in the process list for any mentions of h2o (and if so are they just sitting there, or using a lot of CPU).
Also is this repeatable: you are able to connect the first time, but not reconnect? (If so, what are you doing to reset it again?)